# Convert to readonly collection with AutoMapper

Tags: collections, f#, automapper

I need to find a way to convert list of arbitrary values to another list

AutoMapper works if destination type is `ICollection<>` because it's creating an instance and populating it with `Add`, but my type is immutable list `'a list`

So if I create list of ints:

```ml
let ints = [1; 2; 3]
```

And try to map it to `ResizeArray<int64>` (synonym to `List<T>`) with

```ml
mapper.Map<ResizeArray<int64>>(ints)
```

it will work, but if I try to map it to `int64 list` with

```ml
mapper.Map<int64 list>
```

then it will fail.

I've found a solution that will convert successfully, but it will work only with explicitly defined types

```ml
let cfg = MapperConfiguration(
            fun c ->
                c.CreateMap<int, int64>() |> ignore
                c.CreateMap<int list, int64 list>()
                 .ConvertUsing(
                    fun source _ (cfg: ResolutionContext) ->
                        source
                        |> Seq.map cfg.Mapper.Map<int, int64>
                        |> Seq.toList))
```

So question is: How to write type converter that will convert `'a list` to `'b list` without explicitly defining all possible combinations of these types?

Comment: Why do you want to use AutoMapper for this instead of just List.map?

Comment: @JimFoye, I have complex records with lists of complex records inside. This is simplified version of what I need in the result

Comment: No matter how complex the transformations, you should be able to accomplish them with some combination of F# map functions (Seq.map, List.map, etc.). I still don't understand why you would need to use AutoMapper here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found solution. All I needed is to look at source code of this [ReadOnlyCollection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/ReadOnlyCollectionMapper.cs) mapper

Solution is not perfect, because collection items transformed and inserted into `System.Collections.Generic.List` and afterwards converted to `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`, which have some overhead. But at least it's working

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression;
using AutoMapper.Mappers;
using AutoMapper.Internal;
using static AutoMapper.Internal.CollectionMapperExpressionFactory;
using Microsoft.FSharp.Collections;

    public class SeqToFSharpListMapper : EnumerableMapperBase
    {
        public override bool IsMatch(TypePair context)
            => context.SourceType.IsEnumerableType() 
            && context.DestinationType.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1");

        public override Expression MapExpression(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, ProfileMap profileMap, IMemberMap memberMap,
                                                 Expression sourceExpression, Expression destExpression, Expression contextExpression)
        {
            var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(ElementTypeHelper.GetElementType(destExpression.Type));
            var list = MapCollectionExpression(configurationProvider, profileMap, memberMap, sourceExpression, Default(listType), contextExpression, typeof(List<>), MapItemExpr);

            return Call(typeof(ListModule).GetMethod(nameof(ListModule.OfSeq)).MakeGenericMethod(destExpression.Type.GenericTypeArguments[0]), list);
        }
    }
```

And F#

```ml
    override _.MapExpression (configurationProvider, profileMap, memberMap, sourceExpression, destExpression, contextExpression) =
        let listType = typedefof<System.Collections.Generic.List<_>>.MakeGenericType(ElementTypeHelper.GetElementType destExpression.Type)
        let list = MapCollectionExpression(configurationProvider, profileMap, memberMap, 
                                           sourceExpression, Default(listType), contextExpression,
                                           typedefof<System.Collections.Generic.List<_>>,
                                           MapItem(fun c p s d ctx i -> MapItemExpr(c, p, s, d, ctx, &i))) // compiler require explicit lambda
        upcast Call(typedefof<obj list>.Assembly // don't want to use AssemblyQualifiedName
                        .GetType("Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule") // have to use this trick because we can't access ListModule through typeof
                        .GetMethod("OfSeq")
                        .MakeGenericMethod(destExpression.Type.GenericTypeArguments.[0]),
                    list)
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Open-Generics.html